# Applescript Read specific value in XML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, applescript

I'm trying to read XML using AppleScript.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xfdf xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/">
<annots>
<square            color="#FF0000" creationdate="D:20130828114843+05'30'"            date="D:20130828114901+05'30'" flags="print"            name="Xi6cOkAWgWHcAhpfBkR5A7" page="0"            rect="347.7599999991828,1041.8400000004283,453.5999999989341,1056.9600000003927"            subject="Rectangle"                title="1 im, awltest7 (AWLTEST7.IM)">
<contents-richtext>
<body>
<p>Text Not Clear</p>
</body>
</contents-richtext>
<popup                open="yes" page="0"            rect="453.5999999989341,944.4600000003926,573.5999999989341,1056.9600000003927"/>
</square>
<square            color="#FF0000" creationdate="D:20130828114910+05'30'"            date="D:20130828114919+05'30'" flags="print"            name="ptmmBKtfoDEbVzirMgZLnY" page="0"            rect="511.1999999987987,1092.960000000308,550.7999999987057,1123.9200000002352"            subject="Rectangle"                title="2 im, awltest7 (AWLTEST7.IM)">
<contents-richtext>
<body>
<p>Incorrect dimension</p>
</body>
</contents-richtext>
<popup                open="yes" page="0"            rect="550.7999999987057,1011.4200000002352,670.7999999987056,1123.9200000002352"/>
</square>
<square            color="#FF0000" creationdate="D:20130828114956+05'30'"            date="D:20130828115004+05'30'" flags="print"            name="8LaAl2Upx4LEaQptQKXoZx" page="0"            rect="355.67999999916424,731.5200000011573,431.99999999898483,750.2400000011135"            subject="Rectangle"                title="3 im, awltest7 (AWLTEST7.IM)">
<contents-richtext>
<body>
<p>Incorrect Text</p>
</body>
</contents-richtext>
<popup                open="yes" page="0" rect="431.99999999898483,637.7400000011133,551.9999999989849,750.2400000011135"/>
</square>
</annots>
</xfdf>
```

**AppleScript**

```
set theXMLFile to ((choose file) as string)
tell application "System Events"
    set theXMLFile to XML file theXMLFile
    set squares to XML elements of XML element "annots" of XML element "xfdf" of theXMLFile whose name is "square"
    set p to {}
    set attrs to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to (count squares)
        set end of p to value of XML element "p" of XML element "body" of XML element "contents-richtext" of item i of squares
        set end of attrs to value of XML attributes of XML element "popup" of item i of squares
    end repeat
end tell
```

By using the the script I managed to get the **'< p >'** and **'< popup >'** value. How do I get the **'< square >'** value. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below scripts work.

```
tell application "System Events"
        set theXMLFile to XML file theXMLFile
        set squares to XML elements of XML element "annots" of XML element "xfdf" of theXMLFile whose name is "square"
        set p to {}
        set attrs to {}
        repeat with i from 1 to (count squares)
            set end of p to value of XML element "p" of XML element "body" of XML element "contents-richtext" of item i of squares
            set end of attrs to value of XML attributes of item i of squares
        end repeat
    end tell
```